# Connect multiple external monitors to older Macbook pro from 2011

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, macbook-pro, external-display, mst

I have a Macbook pro from 2011 running Mac os X El Capitan version 10.11.6 with the following technical specification:

**Processor:** 2,2 GHz Intel Core i7 
**Memory:** 8 GB 1333 MHz DDR3 
**Graphic card:** AMD Radeon HD 6750M 512 MB

What I'm trying to do is to connect 2 external monitors to my Macbook so I can get a "Extended display-mode".
The only input port that my Macbook is supporting is Thunderbolt/Minidisplay port.

So what I did was to purchase a Displayport MST-Hub with a Thunderbolt/Minidisplay cable going to the port of my Mac and then I tried to connect one external monitor to that Hub throughout a HDMI-to-Displayport adapter-cable. But somehow I got screen flickering on the external monitor and it just steadily turned on and off.

So Im wondering what am I doing wrong here and have any of you managed to actually successfully connect multiple external monitors to an older Macbook pro in a Extended-mode (not mirrored).

I'm truly grateful for all of your tips and advices here.

*PS! I have already tried another solution which was to purchase a graphic card adapter to connect with USB to my Macbook and then connect my external monitor with HDMI to the adapter. I actually got my desktop showing up on the external screen but it was a very low frequency so it was annoying to use.*

Comment: [apple.se] is usually a better place to ask Mac-specific questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be stuck.
Basically, the 2011 MacBook Pro only supports one external monitor.
Source: [EveryMac](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.5-17-late-2011-unibody-thunderbolt-specs.html)

macOS doesn't support MST, so you'd need a dedicated output for each.
El Capitan doesn't support eGPUs.
Your Mac can't run Mojave, which is minimum requirement for an eGPU.